# Android Dagger after convert code from support android to Androidx Dependency class not working

Tags: android

error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError] dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor was unable to process this class because not all of its dependencies could be resolved. Check for compilation errors or a circular dependency with generated code

I have try to update dagger library to latest 2.28.3 and target sdk to 32. but when I run project error: [ComponentProcessor:MiscError]  occurs.

Comment: There is literally no way anyone can answer this without seeing more of the error or some code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.